# Connect Dell latitude e7440 to two external displays

Tags: dell, display, screen

I am not able to connect Dell latitude e7440 to two external displays. One is 24 inches and second is 27. It only detects the 24 inch one and duplicates everything from that screen onto 27 inch one. I tried swapping the outputs (27 cable where 24 was), but still the same results.

How could I connect these two so that they extend each other(and the laptop screen) and 27 would be with the right resolution?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution?